# Regex to Uncomment an image tag from the rich text editor field using Sitecore Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

What I am trying to achieve here is to fetch the HTML within a rich text editor and I need to uncomment all the img tags which are commented within that HTML. I don't want any other HTML code to get uncomment. For example

**Input** - HTML of rich text having commented tags

**Output** - Only img tag should get uncomment

I am having the regex for two conditions :-
1.) To uncomment all the HTML `<!--(.*?)-->`
2.) To get IMG tag alone from the HTML - `<img([\w\W]+?)/>`

Its not working when I am combining both the REGEX to get my required result. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the regex you're looking for is `<!--\s*(<img[\w\W]+?>)\s*-->`.

I run the following script:

```
$html = '<!-- <img src="-/media/67a6sahgshghs6as76.ashx" alt=""  width="100%" height="auto" class="figure"> -->';
$regex = '<!--\s*(<img[\w\W]+?>)\s*-->';
$matches = ([regex]$regex).Matches($html)
$matches.Groups[1].Value
```

And the output is

```
<img src="-/media/67a6sahgshghs6as76.ashx" alt=""  width="100%" height="auto" class="figure">
```

Remember that parsing html with regex is not recommended. You can try to use a library like `HtmlAgilityPack`. And that the script above only works when `<img` tag is the only content in the html comment.